# Export Neo4j to csv file

Tags: solr, neo4j

I have scenario in which I am using Neo4j for storing data and Solr for suggestion data. 
Suppose i got new value for field 'area' then I have to update it in Neo4j(obviosuly) and in Solr too , so that I can suggestion new 'area' entered to other users. 
Updating records so frequently in Solr could be costly. So what should be the strategy ?

What I am thinking of doing ...
As new area is entered, then I will update it in Neo4j. But I will update Solr only batch wise (after regular interval of time). 
So If I can export Neo4j to some file.csv and then I will update this file to Solr, it will resolve my problem.

So any help in this ....